# Unknown property, please help am getting an error

Tags: visualforce

.bb
            {
                border-bottom: solid 2px black;
                border-top:solid 2px black;
            }

```
         @media print {
         .noprint {display:none;}
          }  
           p.MsoHeader, li.MsoHeader, div.MsoHeader{ 
                margin:0in; 
                margin-top:.0001pt; 
               mso-pagination:widow-orphan; 
               tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in; 
            } 
            p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter{ 
                margin:0in; 
                margin-bottom:.0001pt; 
                mso-pagination:widow-orphan; 
                tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in; 
           } 
            @page Section1{ 
                size:8.5in 11.0in;  
                margin:0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in; 
               mso-header-margin:0.5in; 
                mso-header:h1; 
                mso-footer:f1;  
                mso-footer-margin:0.5in; 
                mso-paper-source:0; 
            } 
           div.Section1{ 
                page:Section1; 
            } 
            /*Below is the style to prevent the repetition of header and Footer.. Cheers!!!*/ 
               margin:0in 0in 0in 9in; 
            }         
       </style> 
    </head>

    <body>
    <table id="table2"  width="100%" style="font-family:Arial,Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">
                             <tr>
                              <td align = "Center"><apex:image style="align-left" height="130px" value="https://c.cs7.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015M0000000C2PA&oid=00DM0000001eY8D&lastMod=1427458066000" /></td>        
                              </tr>
                          </table> 
       <!-- Content --> 
       <div class="Section1"><!--Section1 div starts--> 
            <!-- Page 1 starts --> 
           <br/> 
          <apex:outputText value="{!PrintView}" escape="false"/> 
          <input type="button" id="print" value="Print" class="noprint" onclick="window.print();" />
          <input type="button" id="refresh" value="Back" class="noprint" onclick="window.history.back();" /><br/> 
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width = "100%" style="font-family:Calibri, Arial,Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; "> 
                                      <tr>

                                          <td colspan = "2" width = "50%" align = "Center"><h3>PBO Number: 930025382<br/></h3> </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                      </tr>

                                      <tr><td colspan = "2" width = "50%" align = "Center"><h3>Tax Certificate <br/></h3></td> </tr>
                                     <tr> <td colspan = "2" width = "50%" align = "Center"><h3>This receipt is issued for the purposes of Section 18a of the</h3></td> </tr>
                                      <tr><td colspan = "2" width = "50%" align = "Center"><h3>Income Tax Act, 1962.</h3></td>  </tr>
                                     <tr> <td colspan = "2" width = "50%" align = "Center"><h3>This donation will be used exclusively for the object of
                                                                        The Shine Trust.</h3></td>  </tr>                      
                                  </table> 
          <apex:repeat id="repeatAccount" value="{!lst_ReceiptHeaderwrap}" var="item">
                            <apex:variable var="t" value="{!item.oTaxReceipt}" />
          <br/><br/>

          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width = "100%" style="font-family:Calibri, Arial,Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">                                      
          <tr>
              <td align="center"><h3>Date of Receipt</h3></td>
              <td align="left">
              <apex:outputField value="{!t.Year_end_Words__c }"  />  
              </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
           </tr>  
           <tr>
              <td align="center"><h3>Name of Donor</h3></td>
              <td align="left">
              <apex:outputpanel >
              <apex:outputField value="{!t.Account__r.name}" /> 
              </apex:outputpanel>
              <apex:outputpanel >
              <apex:outputField value="{!t.Contact__r.name}" /> 
              </apex:outputpanel>
              </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top"><h3>Address of Donor</h3></td>
            <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!t.Account__c !=''}">  
              <td align="left">
              <apex:outputField value="{!t.Account__r.BillingStreet}" /><br/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!t.Account__r.BillingCity}" /><br/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!t.Account__r.BillingState}" /><br/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!t.Account__r.BillingPostalCode}" /><br/>
              </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            </apex:outputpanel>
            <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!t.Contact__c !=''}">  
              <td align="left">
              <apex:outputField value="{!t.Contact__r.MailingStreet}" /><br/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!t.Contact__r.MailingCity}" /><br/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!t.Contact__r.MailingState}" /><br/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!t.Contact__r.MailingPostalCode}" /><br/>
              </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            </apex:outputpanel>  
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td align="center"><h3>Amount of Donation</h3></td>
              <td align="left">
              R<apex:outputText value="{!t.Total_Receipt_Amount__c}" />
              </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td align="center"></td>
              <td align="left">
              <apex:image style="align-left" height="130px" value="https://c.cs7.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015M0000000C2PK&oid=00DM0000001eY8D&lastMod=1427458054000" />
              </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top"><h3>Issued by:</h3></td>
              <td align="left">
              Julie Fischer<br/>Manager: Finance <br/>The Shine Trust
              </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
           </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center"><h3>Date:</h3></td>
              <td align="left">
              <apex:outputField value="{!t.TodayDate__c}"/>
              </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="top"><h3>BBBEE Status:</h3></td>
              <td align="left">
              The Shine Trust is a<br/>level 4 BBBEE compliant organisation
              </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
           </tr>                                                                            
          </table>

          <hr/>
          <br/>
          <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width = "70%" style="font-family:Calibri, Arial,Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">                                      
          <tr>
          <td colspan = "2">Summary of donations received for the period <apex:outputLabel > </apex:outputLabel><apex:outputField value="{!t.Year_Start_Words__c}"  /> to <apex:outputLabel > </apex:outputLabel><apex:outputField value="{!t.Year_end_Words__c }"  /> </td>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
          </tr>                                                                               
          </table>                                                                                   
          <table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width = "70%" style="font-family:Calibri, Arial,Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">
                                  <thead bgcolor="#F3F9FF">
                                  <tr>
                                      <th align = "left" width = "50%" height = "25">Month Ending </th>
                                      <th align = "Center" width = "50%" height = "25">Amount (ZAR)</th>
                                  </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                  <tbody>
                                      <apex:repeat value="{!item.receiptset}" var="subitem">
                                      <apex:variable value="{!subitem.oSummary}" var="con" />
                                      <tr>
                                          <td align = "left" width = "50%" height = "25"><apex:outputText value="{!con.ofullmonth}"/> </td>
                                          <td align = "right" width = "50%" height = "25"><apex:outputText value="{0, number,###,##0.00}"><apex:param value="{!con.oQuantity}" /></apex:outputText></td>                                                                                                                                                                     
                                      </tr>                                          
                                      </apex:repeat>
                                      <tr>
                                          <td align = "right" width = "50%" height = "25"></td>
                                          <td class="bb" align = "right" width = "50%" height = "25"><apex:outputText value="{0, number,###,##0.00}"><apex:param value="{!t.Total_Receipt_Amount__c}" /></apex:outputText></td>                                                                                                                                                                     
                                      </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                  </table>

                                  <br/><br/>

      <table id="style2" border="0" width="50%" style="font-family:Arial,Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">
                                <tr>
                                <td style="vertical-align:bottom;">

                                <apex:image style="align-left" width="200px" height="130px" value="https://c.cs7.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015M0000000C2PP&oid=00DM0000001eY8D&lastMod=1427459587000" />

                                </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </table> 
      <br clear="all" style="page-break-before:always" /> 
      <br/>

      </apex:repeat> 



          <!--Header and Footer Starts--> 

        </div><!--Section1 div ends--> 
    </body> 


</html>
```

Comment: Hi Phillip, welcome to SFSE. It's going to be almost impossible to help you unless you tell us exactly what the error is, verbatim, and where in your code it occurs. It's likely your Apex controller might be needed as well. Please take a quick look at [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and come back to add some specifics and details to your question via an edit.

Comment: @DavidReed Thanks David for your quick answer, am trying to create a package including that visualforce page and am getting an error - Unknown property 'TaxReceiptHandler.ReceiptHeaderWrap.receiptset'. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, it's a comprehensible error, but we cannot tell you more than the literal text of the error without more detail. Could you edit your question to include that error detail and include the declarations of `lst_ReceiptHeaderwrap` and the class `TaxReceiptHandler.ReceiptHeaderWrap`?

Comment: Basically the error just means that class doesn't have an accessible property `receiptset`.

Comment: @david Thanks David, am a newbie to Apex side of Salesforce I will read up and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I (and I'm sure others) would be very happy to help and try to provide an answer, we just need some additional information from you to fully identify it. If you can edit those Apex elements into your question I'd be happy to write an answer.

Comment: @DavidReed When I remove // sign on the TaxReceiptHandler I get an error Variable does not exist: c at line 1,425. https://gist.github.com/phillipmcelu/416478de81480aa5b3eac7ac1bfff849

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is probably too large to be fully addressed within the scope of a Stack Exchange answer due to the amount of code that is involved. To summarize quickly, the error

> Unknown property 'TaxReceiptHandler.ReceiptHeaderWrap.receiptset'

indicates that there is a reference within the Visualforce markup to a data element that is not declared in the corresponding Apex class.

That reference appears to be here:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!item.receiptset}" var="subitem">
```

Reviewing the code in your Gist, the class `ReceiptHeaderWrap` is declared as

```
public class ReceiptHeaderWrap{
        public Tax_Receipt__c oTaxReceipt{get;set;}
        public boolean isSelected{get;set;}
       // public List<receiptWrap> receiptset{get;set;}
        public ReceiptHeaderWrap(Tax_Receipt__c a,boolean b /* List<receiptWrap> c */ ){
            oTaxReceipt=a;
            isSelected=b;
           // receiptset=c;            
        }
}
```

Note that the critical property `receiptset` and its corresponding constructor parameter `c` is commented out in three places. Additionally, at line 248, the `lst_ReceiptHeaderwrap` is populated without passing this third parameter due to commenting out.

I don't see any hint as to why the definition of `ReceiptHeaderWrap` was changed. One of two things needs to happen:

1. Undo the commenting in the Apex classes to restore this property, and fix any issues that arise from that change.
2. Remove the `<apex:repeat>` from the Visualforce page.